# How to bring a child process to foreground

Tags: c#, process

I am starting a process which really starts 3 processes. Is there a way to select which child process I want to bring to the front?

Right now I am using:

```cs
try
{
  Process pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(myproc)[0];

  IntPtr handle = pname.MainWindowHandle;
  SetForegroundWindow(handle);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("start, no proc running" + ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is that it seems random which process it brings to the front.

The child process names are Session A, B and C, I want C

Comment: You haven't specified which one of the 3 (Windows) you'ld like to set as foreground (what are the criteria). Or, just one of the 3 processes owns a Window?

Comment: By what rules/knowledge do you know that the wrong window is being brought forward? Window title? Something else? Some clues about those rule(s) would help - because essentially, you're asking us to implement those same rules in your program.

Comment: sorry i fixed the question. The child process names are Session A, B and C, I want C

Comment: You have UIAutomation (see the [AutomationElement.FromHandle()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.fromhandle), then [TryGetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern, out object pattern)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.trygetcurrentpattern). Cast the `pattern` object to `WindowPattern` and see what fields you can set / methods you can call). You can also use [SetForeGroundWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) if you can PInvoke.

Comment: This all, of course, if can actually see a Process named `SessionC` in TaskManager. If not, clarify what is a *child Process* in this context, what is its name, as seen in TaskManager, specify whether this Process owns a Window  and why you cannot single it out, knowing its name.

Comment: Session C is the name of the child process in task manager of the parent process PCSWS.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired window with:

```
Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in ProcessList)
{
    if (process.MainWindowTitle == "Session C")
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("no proc found" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```